# Match two items from one entry in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am building an array in a 'for' loop using the following:

```
$output[] = array('title' => $title, 'start' => $startClean, 'end' => $endClean, 'url' => $url);
```

I need to put a statement around this so if the title and the start date are already in the array, then it skips the above line. Happy with looking for one element in an array - not so sure about two...

Thanks :)

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: You gave up and nobody helped you or what?

Comment: I ended up restructuring the code and doing what I needed a different way as the code as it had been written was causing me various problems. Appreciate the help though :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and check if you have an element already with the same title value and same start value, like this (Where `$titleCheck` and `$startCheck` are the values from the current iteration):

```
if(array_reduce($output, function($keep, $v)use($titleCheck, $startCheck){
    if($v["title"] == $titleCheck && $v["start"] == $startCheck)
        $keep = TRUE;
    return $keep;
}, FALSE)) {
    $output[] = array('title' => $title, 'start' => $startClean, 'end' => $endClean, 'url' => $url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create the array with keys made up of the title and date `$title.$start` so that there will only be one.  So in the loop:

```
$output[$title.$start] = array('title' => $title, 'start' => $startClean, 'end' => $endClean, 'url' => $url);
```

This will effectively yield the last occurrence of title and date.  If you want the first occurrence you can sort it in the reverse on whatever criteria is important.
Then if you want to get rid of those as keys afterward (optional):

```
$output = array_values($output);
```

Comment: Watch out! If you do it this way the last element with the same key will be in the array. If you check it every iteration the first element will be in the array